# SmallCheck generate data satisfying invariants

Tags: haskell, smallcheck

I want to use SmallCheck to test my code. I managed to generate arbitrary lists of pairs of ints, but that's not what my type should contain. The list represents a set of ranges, where `[1,3),[4,6)` would be encoded/stored as `[(1,3),(4,6)]`.

These are the invariants for the normalized form of my ranges:

```
fst a < snd a 
snd a < fst b where a is before b in the list
```

I would like to communicate this to SmallCheck so that it doesn't generate loads of values that I throw away, because they aren't satisfying my invariants, but maybe that's not possible.

How can I generate lists satisfying my invariants?

Comment: you could create a random `[NonNegative Int]` of even length and then use a `scan (+) 0` and a helper function to pair them up.

Comment: ahh and watch out for `Int`-overflows ;-)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, that's clever, but test properties should usually be more obviously correct/complete.

Comment: @dfeuer If I understand correctly this is not the property to prove, but the input for them, the properties themselves should be simple/correct. => added an answer to make this more concrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Favour application-specific types over built-int types (Int, List). This is advice not just for SmallCheck, but for any piece of software, in any language.

```
data Interval = Interval (Int,Int)
data Domain = Domain [Interval]
```

Write smart constructors that enforce your invariants.

```
interval :: Int -> Int -> Interval
interval x y = Interval (min x y, max x y) -- if you want this

domain :: [Interval] -> Domain
domain ints = Domain ... (something that sorts intervals, and perhaps merges them)
```

Then use these to create Serial instances.

Comment: I think sorting/merging is an unnecessary overhead, compared to generating them on their own, if they are just generated for test properties sake

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that this problem is solved better with user-defined types.

I assume you are writing an algorithm that has some property for disjoint half-open intervals sorted in an ascending order, then the following provides `Serial` instances.

I decided to give `Interval` and `AscDisjIntervals` different generators rather than implementing one in terms of the other.

The algorithm for `AscDisjIntervals` is as I already wrote in the comment

- generating a list of non-negative `Integer`s (this is to avoid `Int` overflow)
- summing these integers (this asserts an ascending order of all values
- generating pairs from this list (discarding the last single element if the list has an odd number of elements)

`Intervals.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
module Intervals where

newtype Interval = I (Integer,Integer) deriving(Eq)

instance Show Interval where
    show (I (a,b)) = "["++show a ++ ", "++ show b ++ "]"

instance Monad m => Serial m Interval where
    series = let a_b a b = I (getNonNegative $ min a b , getNonNegative $ max a b) 
             in cons2 a_b

newtype AscDisjIntervals = ADI [Interval] deriving (Eq)

instance Show AscDisjIntervals where
    show (ADI x) = "|- "++ (unwords $ map show x) ++ " ->"

instance Monad m => Serial m AscDisjIntervals where
    series = cons1 aux1

aux1 :: [NonNegative Int] -> AscDisjIntervals
aux1 xx = ADI . generator . tail $ scanl (+) 0 xx
  where generator [] = []
        generator (_:[]) = []
        generator (x:y:xs) = let i = I (getNonNegative x ,getNonNegative y)
                        in i:generator xs
```

Note: I only compiled the program and did not test any properties.